# Как происходит вызов метода одного объекта в разных потоках java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Класс потокобезопасный, в памяти один экземпляр, и если вызвать один и тот же метод у этого объекта в разных потоках, как будет исполняться код? То есть состояние объекта общее для всех потоков, так как
в моем случае класс потокобезопасный, нет изменяемых переменных, то можно представить, что у каждого потока свой экземпляр объекта? Один поток может выполнять например одну инструкцию в методе, другой поток может тоже выполнять эту же инструкцию в этом же методе, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Выполнение одного вызова метода не мешает другому вызову, вопрос в том параллельны ли вычисления в `JVM` я точно не знаю, но мне кажется там может и не быть настоящей многопоточности, в конечном счете все это влияет на результаты выполнения, получаемые данные именно они в какой-то момент могут быть не теми которые мы ожидаем из-за того что поток исполнения не прямолинейный а разветвленный. Обычно потокобезопасные операции осуществляют блокировку, тут ее не будет, проверить это легко — нужно сделать вызовы с разной частотой.

Comment: В мультизадачной операционной системе потоки выполняются асинхронно. Если экземпляр один, то своего экземпляра не будет. Понимаешь неправильно, потокобезорасный класс даёт выполнять код только одному потоку.

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: "потокобезорасный класс даёт выполнять код только одному потоку" - это неправильно, вводите в заблуждение. Это один из способов сделать класс потокобезопасным, но далеко не единственный. Например, в immutalbe классе, или stateless классе нет необходимости ограничивать число потоков, которые могут выполнятся одновременно. И класс при этом остается потокобезопасным.